# How to serve external js file to node.js server

Tags: node.js

can you help me I downloaded the js file for socket.io browser client.and put it on a js folder...but I am having problem node.js doesn't serves me the external js

```
<script src="./js/socketio.js"></script>
```

how do I serve the external js file ?

Here is the app.js server code

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                return res.end('Error loading index.html');
            }

            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });


}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And how does your nodejs code look like?

Comment: @Sirko, I added now the app.js code

Comment: In your app.js you always stream out the `index.html`. How should the result ever be the js file?

Comment: @Sirko,  how do I modify that so that i can access the socketio client lib. ?

Comment: I'd use some library for http servers like express.js. If you do not want to use those, you have to get the requested file from the `req` parameter and serve that.

Comment: @Sirko, without express is that hard to accomplished ?

Comment: Somewhere in the `req` object there is the request file, but I think, that express or something similar will make your life much easier

Comment: @Sirko, I have not yet tried the express.js but can you please show me snippet for the express.js ?

Comment: Look at http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html and http://socket.io/docs/# (2nd example).